# Is there a way to combine these 2 methods?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following two methods:

```
class Debug
{
    static bool OutputToConsole = true;

    public static void Log(string Type, string URL, StringBuilder Parameters)
    {
        string Output = Type + ":" + new string(' ', 9 - Type.Length) + URL + " { " + Parameters.ToString() + " }";
        Trace.WriteLine(Output);
        if(OutputToConsole) Console.WriteLine(Output);
    }

    public static void Log(string Data)
    {
        string Output = "Response: " + Data;
        Trace.WriteLine(Output);
        if(OutputToConsole) Console.WriteLine(Output);
    }
}
```

If you'll notice, it's only the `string Output` that changes.

The 2 lines after it are the same in both methods.

I was just wondering if there is there a way to keep to the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and combine these 2 methods?

Comment: introduce a helper function `trace(string output)`?

Comment: Make a method that is effectively the same as the second overload, only without adding the "Response:" first? You can then string.Format any way you like and call it with the result. But really, for two lines twice why would you bother?

Comment: @Jon Just for the sake of curiosity, mostly. To see whether something like this is possible. Could come in handy in the future in a "better" implementation.

Comment: Have you tried passing `string Data` as a fourth parameter in the first method? It seems to me that you could just concatenate the `Data` string to what you build in `string Output`?

Comment: Seems like a question better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Just like any DRY problem, put it in one place (a method) and see how you can get access to that where you need it (method calls).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refactor the common code to a private helper function: (Visual studio will do all of this for you by highlighting the relevant section of code, right clicking, and choosing Refactor -> extract method...)

```
private static void LogHelper(string text)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(text);
    if(OutputToConsole) Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

(Note the name change to ensure it has a different signature from `Log(string Data)`.)

Then just call that function from both of the others.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that Servy! I've accepted your answer over the others because of the *Refactor -> Extract method* tip; useful!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how much of an improvement this is...

```
class Debug
{
    static bool OutputToConsole = true;

    public static void LogRequest(string type, string url, StringBuilder params)
    {
        log(type + ":" + new string(' ', 9 - type.Length) + url + " { " + params.ToString() + " }");
    }

    public static void LogResponse(string data)
    {
        log("Response: " + data);
    }

    private static void log(string msg)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(msg);
        if(OutputToConsole) Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Kohanz! This is exactly what I've ended up doing, but I chose @Servy's answer for the useful tip in it. It was close!

Comment: @DannyBeckett Glad I could help and thanks for providing your reasoning; I agree!

Answer (score 1):

There is likely no way to **combine** the two methods and get any real *value out of it* because the `Output` generated is different, but you could create a method that does the actual trace:

```
public static void Trace(string Output)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(Output);
    if(OutputToConsole) Console.WriteLine(Output);
}
```

and then call that from those methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could use optional parameters if you wanted, it's a bit unusual, but interesting:

```
public static void Log(string Data = null, string Type = null, string URL = null, StringBuilder Parameters = null)
{
    string Output = "";
    if (Data != null)
    {
        Output = "Response: " + Data;
    }
    else if (Type != null && URL != null && Parameters != null)
    {
        Output = Type + ":" + new string(' ', 9 - Type.Length) + URL + " { " + Parameters.ToString() + " }";
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Provide yada yada arguments lala");
    }
    Trace.WriteLine(Output);
    if (OutputToConsole) Console.WriteLine(Output);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Log(Data: "Test");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Log(Type: "myType", URL: "www.bla", Parameters: sb);
```